# why is mysqld process top process?

Tags: mysql, rsync

I can hear something pounding away on my hard drive.
I look at top and see mysqld as top process, high 30 to 40% all the time.
No I did not start any process with mysqld.
I just ran a "pkexec rsync ..." with a long line of parameters to back up my entire system to a local attached hard drive. Took 4plus days. Now mysqld is pounding away on something.
Any ideas?

How does one find out what mysqld is doing?
Should I kill it?
Should I shut down?
What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Inside mysql do

```
 show full processlist
```

and you get shown what mysql is doing with at the beginning of the result process ids. You can use, still inside mysql ...

```
kill {processlist}
```

to kill a process.

But do note the sql statement and check if it is correct: it is possible to create mysql statements that take longer to finish, or never finish, due to wrongly created joins or a missing index.